# won't accept a null object in C#

Tags: c#, object, nullable, nullreferenceexception

When I run my code it tells me that the object of adr is null, and thats true, but why wont it work when it works in a duplicate of the same method, with the exeption of insert instead of select.

the code looks like this:

```
public City doesExist(string postnr, string navn, City city, SqlConnection con)
{
    DatabaseConnection.openConnection(con);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("select Id from [By] where Postnummer='" + postnr + "' and Navn='" + navn + "'", con))
    {
        command.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            city.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            city.postnr = postnr;
            city.navn = navn;
            reader.Close();

            return city;
        }

        reader.Close();
        return null;
    }
}

public City create(string postnr, string navn, City city, SqlConnection con)
{
    DatabaseConnection.openConnection(con);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into [By] (Postnummer, Navn) values ('" + postnr + "', '" + navn + "'); select @@identity as 'identity';", con))
    {
        object ID = command.ExecuteScalar();

        city.id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        city.postnr = postnr;
        city.navn = navn;
        return city;
    }
}
```

the call looks like this:

```
City city = new City();
city = city.doesExist(zip, by, city, connection); // this works fine
if (city == null)
{
     // I know that city is null
     // tried inserting City city = new City(); same error
     city = city.create(zip, by, city, connection); // this is where the null error occours
}
```

Comment: Why is the `create` method an instance method of the `City` class? Of course it will throw an exception. After all, `city` is null, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't that 'Create' method need to be `static`?

Comment: Note that your `doesExist` method also takes an input `city` parameter which is unused, and should be removed. Actually, both of these methods look like repository methods, i.e. they should not be **instance** methods of a city class (because they don't belong to a single city instance).

Comment: **warning** your code *may* be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @DanielA.White do you have a quick link on how to prevent those attacks?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard check out JonSkeet's answer below.

Comment: The simple way to prevent Sql Injection attacks is to use parametized queries, instead of building SQL commands with string concatenation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well yes, look:

```
if (city == null)
{
    // If we've got in here, we know that city is a null reference, but...
    city = city.create(...);
}
```

You're calling a method on a reference which is *definitely* null. That's guaranteed to throw a `NullReferenceException`.

You almost certainly want to make your `create` method static (and rename it to comply with normal .NET naming conventions), and call it as

```
city = City.Create(...);
```

You'll also need to remove the `city` parameter from the method call, and instead create a new `City` object *inside* your method. For example:

```
public static City Create(string postnr, string navn, SqlConnection con)
{
    DatabaseConnection.openConnection(con);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand
         ("insert into [By] (Postnummer, Navn) values (@postnr, @navn); "+
          "select @@identity as 'identity';", con))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@postnr", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = postnr;
        command.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = navn;
        object ID = command.ExecuteScalar();

        City = new City();
        city.id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        city.postnr = postnr;
        city.navn = navn;
        return city;
    }
}
```

Note how I've changed your code to use parameterized SQL too. You really, really, shouldn't put values directly into your SQL statement like that - it opens up your system to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and makes various conversions messy.

Additionally, I would recommend creating a new `SqlConnection` (and closing it) for each database operation.

Frankly it's a bit odd for `doesExist` to be an instance method, too... and again, for it to take a `city` parameter.

I would suggest changing the design of this so that you have a `CityRepository` (or something similar) which knows the connection string, and exposes:

```
// I'd rename these parameters to be more meaningful, but as I can't work out what they're
// meant to mean now, it's hard to suggest alternatives.
public City Lookup(string postnr, string nav)

public City Create(string postnr, string nav)
```

The repository would know the relevant connection string, and would be responsible for all the database operations. The `City` type would know nothing about databases.

Comment: ...and probably remove the `city` parameter from the method as well.

Comment: +1: for removing the Sql Injection vulnerability at the same time.

Comment: Wont closing and reopening a database connection in every method slow the loading process, instead of opening one connectione, do all the call, and then closing it?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard: No - the connection pool will handle the "real" connections for you, and it will make sure you don't end up trying to do two things on the same connection at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a method on object class that has not been initialized/is null.

You need to make `City.create` a static member.

```
public static City create(string postnr, string navn, City city, SqlConnection con)
{
    DatabaseConnection.openConnection(con);
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into [By] (Postnummer, Navn) values ('" + postnr + "', '" + navn + "'); select @@identity as 'identity';", con))
    {
        object ID = command.ExecuteScalar();

        city.id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
        city.postnr = postnr;
        city.navn = navn;
        return city;
    }
}
```

And use it like :

```
if(city==null) 
{
    City city = City.create(... );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the better way :

```
 static public City create(string postnr, string navn, SqlConnection con)
 {
     DatabaseConnection.openConnection(con);
     using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into [By] (Postnummer, Navn) values ('" + postnr + "', '" + navn + "'); select @@identity as 'identity';", con))
     {
         object ID = command.ExecuteScalar();

         City city = new City();
         city.id = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
         city.postnr = postnr;
         city.navn = navn;
         return city;
     }

     return null;
 }
```

Create method must be static, and no need to have city in argument.
Call it with :

```
 if (city == null)
 {
      city = City.Create(.....);
 }
```